# Why two exports would be different and How to identify the differences

Tags: tasks, data, data-export, activity

I have two exports.

One of the activity object at the end of November.
One of the activity object at the end of December.

Both are the same queries and neither have date restrictions(so they encompass all activity records).

The December export is a few mb less in file size. Each file is over 500mb.

No activity records are returned with isDeleted.

If records were deleted, they would show up in the isDeleted query correct?

I tried comparing the two files with a code differential, but I run out of memory before the operation completes.

In addition to query differences, deleted records, or changes in field information is there any other reason why these two exports may be different sizes?

What is the best way to determine the difference between the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to determine the difference between the files?

[`csvdiff`](https://pypi.org/project/csvdiff/) can be helpful here (n.b. not my project, just something I've used).

> In addition to query differences, deleted records, or changes in field information is there any other reason why these two exports may be different sizes?

I would guess at a pretty high likelihood that [Activity Archiving](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_archive.htm) is the cause.

Comment: Activity archiving it was. Thank you!